# Validating a value in a named range on separate sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a validation that looks up whether the value in column O (Template sheet) is found on another sheet's column A (CountryState Codes sheet). Column A is a named range called CountryCodes.
If the value is not found then I want to highlight the cell and print an error statement.
The highlight and error code works as I have used it on a different macro but I cannot get the lookup to work. Here is what I currently have:

```
Sub CCtest()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Worksheets("Template").Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range("O2:" & "O" & lastRow)
    If c.Value = Sheets("CountryState Codes").Range("CountryCodes").Value Then
    cell.Offset(0, -14).Value = cell.Offset(0, -14).Value & ", Country Code error"
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Application.Match` or `Application.CountIfs`. Note that this can be achieved with a formula and conditional formatting, w/o VBA.

Comment: I opted for an `application.vlookup` but excel is expecting a list separator after "CountryState Codes" ```CountryCheck = application.worksheetfunction.Vlookup(Country, CountryState Codes!A:A,1, FALSE)")```. Any idea why?

Comment: You're mixing formula notation and VBA notation.

Comment: `Application.Vlookup(Country, Sheets("CountryState Codes").Range("CountryCodes"),1,0)`.

Comment: Got it, thank you it is now working :)